# What does the asterisk in the output of `reveal_type` mean?

Tags: python, types, mypy

```
reveal_type(1) # Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
bla = [1,2,3]
reveal_type(bla[0]) # Revealed type is 'builtins.int*'
reveal_type(bla[0] * 2) # Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```

What is the difference between `int` and `int*`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means that particular type was inferred by mypy as a part of performing type variable substitution.

For example, `blah[0]` is actually doing `blah.__getitem__(0)`: it turns out that the `__getitem__` method is defined to return some value of type `_T`, where `_T` is whatever type is contained within the list*.

Mypy understands that `blah` contains ints, and so inferred that the `_T` return type is of type `int`.

In contrast, there's no type variable inference going on with just `1` and `blah[0] * 2`. The former is a literal; the latter is invoking the `int.__mul__(...)` method, which is typed to return specifically an int.

<sub>*Well, that's not actually the exact signature, but close enough.</sub>

---

For the most part, you can ignore this and just treat it as an implementation detail of mypy. It exists mostly because being able to tell whether or not a type was inferred is occasionally useful to have when you're tinkering with or debugging mypy internals.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @wjandrea -- Not anymore. This question and answer is actually a bit out-of-date now -- mypy [stopped using the asterisk to mark inferred types](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10076) earlier this year.