# How to force mypy's reveal_type to reveal super type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

[Given](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=b7cbbf20fc088886a31d76b33ea05e83):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Sequence

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    pass

class B(A[Sequence[T]], Generic[T]):
    pass

b: B[int] = B()
```

`reveal_type(b)` is `B[int]` as expected. Is there any way for `reveal_type` to instead tell me `A[Sequence[int]]`?

In this simple example this isn't useful, but in the case I am debugging knowing how the supertype was parametrized given a parametrized subtype without having to manually connect the dots (and potentially contradict what `mypy` infers) would clear up things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a helper:

```
def as_a(a: A[T]) -> A[T]:
    return a

reveal_type(as_a(b))
```

On the mypy playground, this reveals `main.A[typing.Sequence*[builtins.int*]]`. ([Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498575/what-does-the-asterisk-in-the-output-of-reveal-type-mean) the asterisks mark types inferred during type variable substitution.)