# Python: annotating a function that instantiates TypedDicts

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function `f` which takes as argument a TypedDict class, and returns an instance of this class.

I've tried the following implementation using `TypeVar`. However when passing around the result of `f`, mypy complains about it not having the correct type. I've narrowed it down to the snippet below:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, TypedDict


T = TypeVar("T")


def f(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()


class Foo(TypedDict):
    pass


f_foo: Foo = f(Foo)

reveal_type(f(Foo))
```

The output of mypy is then:

```
test.py:15: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Foo", variable has type "Foo")
test.py:17: note: Revealed type is "test.Foo*"
```

Why is the type of `f(Foo)` `test.Foo*` instead of `TypedDict('test.Foo', {})`?

Comment: what does the function reveal_type look like?  When I run ```type(f(Foo))``` it yields ```dict``` which is what I would expect.

Comment: @itprorh66 [`reveal_type` is a mypy internal](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#reveal-type).

Comment: Not familiar with mypy but see this for possible solution [How to force mypy's reveal_type to reveal super type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925028/how-to-force-mypys-reveal-type-to-reveal-super-type), it looks similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks @itprorh66. My goal is not to fix the output of `reveal_type` though, but rather to get rid of the mypy error.

Comment: Wild.  After playing around with it, my best guess is that some kind of magic happens when you actually instantiate a `TypedDict` that doesn't translate via the `TypeVar`.  Seems worth filing a mypy bug against.

Comment: Thanks @Samwise - [done](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12310)

Comment: It seems like a bug in **mypy** to me. In terms of **Pyright** this code is correct.